# ¿Cómo contar el numero de veces que aparece un valor?

Tags: r

Mi duda es la siguiente, si tengo el siguiente objeto `a = c(0,0,0,1,1,1)`. ¿Qué comando puedo utilizar para que me cuente solamente los 0?

Comment: Bienvenido pablo  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más sencilla, en caso que `a` sea un vector u objeto similar es

```
sum(a == 0)
```

- `a == 0` retorna un vector de lógicos, dónde `TRUE` representa los lugares dónde el elemento es `0`
- `sum()` hace una suma de valores numéricos, la entrada, al ser un vector de lógicos se transforma automáticamente a un vector de numéricos, dónde `TRUE=1` y `FALSE=0`, por lo que el resultado será en definitiva los valores iguales a 0.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio

Answer (score -1):

Creas el objeto, con as.data.frame lo que haces es convertirlo directamente a una tabla:

```
a <- as.data.frame(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

Cambiamos el nombre de la columna:

```
names(a) = c("N")
```

Y ahora ejecuta ftable(a), lo que hará que te muestre un resumen, en mi ejemplo hay 5 ceros y 3 unos.

```
> table(a)
a
0 1 
5 3
```